# Symfony Error: Attempted to call an undefined method named […] of class

Tags: php, symfony

I'm currently upgrading from Symfony 2.3 to 2.8 and are deprecating for the 3.0 update.
Under the link below, I rewrite `Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\ChoiceList\ChoiceList` and `Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\ChoiceList\LazyChoiceList`.
Among them, the following error occurred.
I wondered if I should add `getChoices()`, so I added it to ChoiceLoader.php, but I still got an error.
How should I solve it?
Also, choice_list will be abolished soon, so I plan to rewrite it.

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.7/UPGRADE-2.7.md

Error

```
Attempted to call an undefined method named "getChoices" of class 
"Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\Factory\DefaultChoiceListFactory"
```

ChoiceList->ChoiceLoader.php

```php
namespace Ahi\Sp\AdminBundle\Form\ChoiceList;
//Remove
//use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\ChoiceList\ChoiceList;
//use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\ChoiceList\LazyChoiceList;
//Add
use Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\Factory\DefaultChoiceListFactory;
use Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\Loader\ChoiceLoaderInterface;

class StaffChoiceLoader implements ChoiceLoaderInterface
{
    private $staffService;
    private $loginStaff;
    private $currentStaff;

    public function __construct($staffService, $loginStaff)
    {
        $this->staffService = $staffService;
        $this->loginStaff = $loginStaff;
    }

    public function loadChoiceList($value = null)
    {
        // Get the same shop staff as the login staff
        $staffs = $this->staffService->getStaffByShop($this->loginStaff->getShop());

        // If the current staff is not included in the acquired staff (due to transfer etc.), add it to the end
        if ($this->currentStaff && !array_search($this->currentStaff, $staffs)) {
            $staffs[] = $this->currentStaff;
        }
        //Remove
        //return new ChoiceList($staffs, $staffs);
        //Add
        return new DefaultChoiceListFactory($staffs, $staffs);
    }

        //Add
        public function loadChoicesForValues(array $values, $value = null)
    {
        if (empty($choices)) {
            return array();
        }

        $values = array();
        foreach ($choices as $person) {
            $values[] = (string) $staff->getId();
        }

        return $values;
    }

    public function loadValuesForChoices(array $choices, $value= null)
    {
        if (empty($values)) {
            return array();
        }

        return $this->staffService->getStaffByShop($this->loginStaff->getShop());
    }
    public function getChoices()
    {
    }
}
```

ArticleType.php

```php
        //Remove
        //$authorChoiceList = new StaffChoiceLoader($this->staffService, $options['login_staff']);
        //Add
        $factory = new DefaultChoiceListFactory();
        $authorChoiceList = $factory->createListFromLoader(new StaffChoiceLoader($this->staffService, $options['login_staff']));

        $builder->add("author", "entity", array(
            "required" => true,
            "class" => "AhiSpCommonBundle:Staff",
            "choice_list" => $authorChoiceList,
            "empty_value" => "Please select",
        ));
```

Comment: In general, deleting a question and then reposting it tends to be frowned upon.  And while I am not positive, changing user names seldom helps either.